# Angularjs - how to prevent same watched expression be evaluated multiple times?

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-digest

While profiling Angularjs app I can see that on a slow page digest runs 5 times and many expressions evaluated too many times and many expensive controller functions are called multiple times as well.
Is there a way to prevent watched expression from being evaluated more than 1 time within a single digest?

Few examples to better illustrate the question:

1. I have an icon picker with 300+ icons, each icon has `{background: colorPicker.color}`
2. I have a very expensive function to check if page is modified and needs saving. It does a deep equals on initial version and current version of a very large object.

So I know that when digest is running I do not need to re-evaluate these.
I would like to have a way to cache calculated values within a single digest cycle.

One time binding is not an option, these watched expressions do change, just not within single digest.

Comment: Can't you use one-time binding for 1. (ng-style I guess)? As for 2. I think some code could help

Comment: Bill, I can't - component shows a set of 300+ icons all on a custom background you can pick in a color picker right there. So while user can pick colors - it is same for all 300 icons. I think I've already worked through all things we can do one-time like labels and other static text.